# Indetermiante form limits question.

Tags: limits

I have a simple question. I learned these things years ago but cannot recall how to prove this. I am interested in the right hand limit

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} e^{-\tfrac{a}{2x}}$$

where $a$ is just some constant different to zero.

My intuition is that this goes to zero as the exponential decays much faster than the square root.

I tried to use L'Hôpital but it didn't help. Did I make a mistake or do I just need to keep applying it over and over again.
\begin{gather}
f(x) = e^{-\frac{a}{2x}}
\\
g(x) = \sqrt{x}
\\
\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = -(\frac{a}{2x^2}e^{-\frac{a}{2x}})(2\sqrt{x})
\end{gather}
Am I just missing something? I feel like I am forgetting something very very basic. I also considered expanding the exponential in Taylor series but that didn't really help

Comment: Make the substitution $x=1/y$.

Comment: I suppose $a$ is a _positive_ non-zero constant?

Comment: Thanks @Mindlack. I think that works out ok. Is that a standard kind of technique or did you just know from practice? .

Comment: @StackTD. Yes, we can assume a positive

Comment: TCD: I wouldn’t say it is a standard technique because in general, substitutions in limits are little more than rewriting stuff with no change in viewpoint (the expression can definitely look simpler, but it is sort of artificial, we just split the complexity). Moreover, that’s a rather standard example, so that is practice (try and understand what happens to all the derivatives of the function when the argument goes to $0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler if you do $\sqrt{x}=1/t$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}te^{-at^2/2}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{at^2/2}}
$$